# PDF file basic usage in cocoa(objective c)

Tags: cocoa, pdf

Can anybody please give me a step by step guide on how to use a locally saved pdf file in a cocoa application and display its contents?
P.S.I am basically a noob in cocoa , and I want to have a proper idea of what I am learning.Therefore I need a step to guide on this. 
Thanks,
Animesh

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any step by step guide. Apple has the PDFKit framework to display PDF files. Read the *PDFKit Programming Guide*, which is part of Apple's developer documentation. For the user interface you need a window and a PDF view to display the contents of the PDF file.

Keep in mind that PDFKit is not a beginning technology. If you are learning Cocoa and Objective-C, you should start with a simpler project before you move on to displaying PDF files. An example of a simpler project would be an app that converts temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit or the other way around.